# How to show the ID of the oldest running docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I using docker `Docker version 1.3.2, build 50b8feb`. There are some new filters for the `ps` command, but it seems nothing provide what I need. I just want to see the oldest container running, to kill it, wait and kill the next oldest one. I hope somebody can come around with some bash magic I am not able to see at the moment. Thanks!

UPDATE:

`sort` does not what I want since it also resorts before reverting order.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, captain obvious. I just needed to use `tail`.

```
docker ps -aq | tail -n 1
```